# changing the datatype of an item in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a `.txt` file with 20,000 lines of this kind of dictionary:

```
{ "seller_cd":"20559","order_cd":"121213123123","items":[{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"ABC","width":"16.9","height":"3.4","depth":"13.8", "qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"4232","item_name":"xyz","width":"16.9","height":"1.5", "depth":"11.8","qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"xz","width":"16.6","height":"3.9","depth":"13.7","qty":"6"}]}
```

I am trying to change the datatype for `"width", "height", "depth"` to `int/float` value.

I tried to convert it into a dataframe and then covert the datatype but I guess there can be an easier way of doing it. Is there an efficient way to solve this in pandas or just a file operation? I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I think non pandas solution is better here.

Comment: you could try importing the data using `json.load()` and pass in an `object_hook` parameter, this lets you modify how the [json decoder functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think vanilla python is fine for this, 20k lines is not that many at all.

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
from ast import literal_eval


file = 'path_to_file'
with open(file,'r') as f:
    json_object = json.load(f) 


for item in json_object['items']:
    item['width'] =  literal_eval(item['width'])
    item['height'] = literal_eval(item['height'])
    item['depth'] =  literal_eval(item['depth'])
```

---

```
with open(Path(file).parent.joinpath('outfile.json'),'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_object ,f)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a ton. I am getting some error `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 443)`

Comment: on which line of code? @prb07 is your file an actual json object?

Comment: the file is not a json object. I have a `text file` with a long dictionary on each line. there are 20,000 dictionaries like this.

Comment: how is it structured?

Comment: @Manakin consider it as one entry of a dictionary per line.

Comment: @WaveShaper I have updated the question with the format of the dictionary. (every line has this dictionary format of the `data.txt` file )

Comment: @prb07 my bad i missed this, is your question up to date with the representative data from your file?